# Compare datetime property to certain date via HQL (.Net)

Tags: .net, datetime, hql, compare

I have problems comparing the datetime property of objects and when trying to
compare to a given date. For example, I tried

```
 IQuery query1 = session.CreateQuery(String.Format(
            @"Select s.Id  
            From InventoryProductStateItem s
            Where s.ValidFrom = " + stateItem.ValidFrom));
```

but get an exception "Incorrect syntax".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates can be compared by passing a parameter to the query:

```
IQuery query1 = session.CreateQuery(String.Format(
            @"Select s.Id  
            From InventoryProductStateItem s
            Where s.ValidFrom = :stateDate)")).SetParameter("stateDate", state.ValidFrom);
```